# Why is this .htaccess not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote this .htacess file and everything seems working except for the **thread.php** and **profile.php** rule, the two rules does not work at the same time unless I comment on one. What could be the problem?

below is the code

```
#1 --- prevent file listing in all of your folder ----

IndexIgnore *

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

#2 Force www before SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#3 Force SSL
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

#4 index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#5 App rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /thread.php?id=$1 [L]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#6 Establish a custom 404 page not found ----

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your profile rule will also match anything that matches the thread rule. Swap the order, so the thread rule goes first, and you should be ok.

Comment: hello, Thank you so much. It is now working but you said that "i have bigger problems", please what could be the problems and also how can i make the code better.

Comment: Actually it's ok, my mistake, you are checking for the URL existing with ".php" added before running the rule, so it's ok. What I would say is that it's bad for performance having so many file system checks. It could probably be done a better way. But that's a bigger question and out of scope here; it would require re-thinking the whole thing. Remember this is going to get run through at least twice for every request, so think how many times the file system is having to be checked.

Comment: Please accept my answer using the tick at the top right of it to show it's worked for you. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)